# use componentDidUpdate code along with DidMount and UnMount in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to migrate my code to new react which supports react hooks. I am using useReducer, useState and useEffect. I could use the `DidMount` and `UnMount` in my code but do not have idea on how i implement `DidUpdate` part as this one might create a re-rendering issue.

Here is how i have done

old code

```
class ImageBoard extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        canvas: undefined,
        selected: undefined
      };
    }

    handleDeleteKey(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 8) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.selected !== undefined) {
          this.state.canvas.remove(this.state.selected);
          this.setState({ selected: undefined });
        }
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
      document.addEventListener("keydown",this.handleDeleteKey.bind(this),false);
      canvas.on("object:selected", e => this.setState({ selected: e.target }));
      canvas.on("selection:cleared", e => this.setState({ selected: undefined }));
      this.setState({ canvas: canvas });
      this.setCanvasBackground(this.props.getSelectedImage, canvas);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (prevProps.getSelectedImage !== this.props.getSelectedImage) {
        this.setCanvasBackground(this.props.getSelectedImage,this.state.canvas);
      }

    }
```

changed to following new code

```
const ImageBoard = () => {
  let canvasEl = React.useRef(null);
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(null)
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = React.useState(null)
 const [state, _] = React.useReducer(imagesReducer, [])

  const handleDeleteKey = event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 8) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (selected !== undefined) {
        canvas.remove(selected);
        setSelected(undefined);
      }
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
    document.addEventListener(
      "keydown",
      handleDeleteKey,
      false
    );
    canvas.on("object:selected", e => setSelected(e.target));
    canvas.on("selection:cleared", e => setSelected(undefined));
    setCanvas(canvas);
    setCanvasBackground(state.images.selectedImage, canvas);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleDeleteKey, false);
    }
  }, [])
```

How do i write this following snippet in useEffect?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
          if (prevProps.getSelectedImage !== this.props.getSelectedImage) {
            this.setCanvasBackground(this.props.getSelectedImage,this.state.canvas);
          }
          this.setCanvasBackground(this.props.getSelectedImage,this.state.canvas);
        }
```

Comment: I was under the impression that hooks can be used in functional components only

Comment: What is prevProps.getSelectedImage !== this.props.getSelectedImage check for? It results in calling setCanvasBackground twice with same arguments. Is this really needed? If you want to avoid unnecessary updates, making a component pure would help.

Comment: @estus code updated now. sorry there was mistakenly same code repeated.

Comment: I've tried to explain this. It's remains unclear how `this.props.getSelectedImage` in class component became `state.images.selectedImage` in functional component, functional component doesn't even use `props`, you will have to figure this inconsistency out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to avoid unnecessary updates when same props are received and this applies to all props and not just `getSelectedImage`, a component can be made pure:

```
const ImageBoard = memo(props => { ... });
```

So the component will be re-rendered only when new props are received, including `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // runs every time the component is rendered
    setCanvasBackground(props.getSelectedImage, canvas);
  })
```

If a part of a component should be evaluated only when new value of specific prop like `getSelectedImage` is received, this is done with `useMemo` or `useEffect` hook, depending on the case. Since `useEffect` can act as both `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount`, this should be taken into account.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // runs once on mount
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
    document.addEventListener(
      "keydown",
      handleDeleteKey,
      false
    );
    canvas.on("object:selected", e => setSelected(e.target));
    canvas.on("selection:cleared", e => setSelected(undefined));
    setCanvas(canvas);
    // setCanvasBackground is moved to another hook
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleDeleteKey, false);
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    // runs every time new getSelectedImage is received, including initial render
    setCanvasBackground(props.getSelectedImage, canvas);
  }, [props.getSelectedImage])
```

Comment: if i use class based way, the image board gets new selected image but my and your way it does not work.

Comment: The code I posted matches componentDid* lifecycle, that's how it's done with hooks. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem. It's unknown why it doesn't work in your case. As I mentioned, you don't use `props` in refactored component for some reason, I wouldn't expect it to be workable.

Comment: I have posted the whole code here. https://gist.github.com/MilanRgm/47c68ad9c2a5a295f32ffaab21f2bb26 . can you look at this, please?

Comment: Fixing the entire application to work is out of the scope of original question. I've tried to answer it directly (how useEffect counterpart to didUpdate can be implemented). Sorry, I can't help for now with this. The application appears to be complex and requires some serious time investment. A *minimal* way to replicate the problem would help, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . So would a live demo like Stackblitz. Consider issuing a bounty or re-asking a new question regarding new problem i(the app that is supposed to work but it doesn't) if you won't receive a suitable answer soon.

Comment: Btw, there shouldn't be `setCanvasBackground` in mount `useEffect`, also I'm not sure why you used `canvasRef` in one place and `canvasState` in another. And another point I didn't mention is there may be no reason to convert to hooks at all. They are a matter of preference and aren't really better than classes. Actually, they often lead to more convoluted implementation in my experience because of a couple of pitfalls. I believe this may be the case here.

Comment: sorry i will ask in a new question. I might be wrong, but i used setCanvasBackground in didMount so i can show default image by pulling the image from initialState. canvasRef is the instance of canvas element and canvasState has other values of canvas related.

Comment: Here is a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276103/selected-image-is-not-displayed-in-image-board . The component is not rendered when image is selected/clicked in functional way.

Comment: @Serenity I assume you may want to use `canvasRef` as `useRef` consistently in the component instead of `canvas` local variable and `canvasState`. This is one of hook pitfalls I mentioned. I will try to take a look at new question once I will have time. A demo would increase the chances for the question to be answered it's complex enough so it needs to be debugged by a person who answers it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **useEffect()** hook to implement **componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, componentWillUnmount** in the following way

```
   const mounted = useRef()
   const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0)

   useEffect(() => {
        let timeout
        if (!mounted.current) {
            // do componentDidMount logic

            console.log('mount')
            mounted.current = true
        } else {
            // do componentDidUpdate logic
   
            timeout = setInterval(() => {
               setCount(prev => prev + 1)
            }, 3000)
        }

            return () => {
                // do componentWillUnmount logic
                clearInterval(timeout)
            }
    }, [ count ])
```